# How to get the secret's value from Key Vault in Configuration Builder

Tags: c#, azure, connection-string, azure-keyvault

I've followed some of the docs out there. So, setup the config builder, I added this code:

```cs
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
builder.AddAzureKeyVault($"https://{Configuration.GetSection("Azure")["KeyVaultName"]}.vault.azure.net/", keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
```

Now, I am trying to get the value from the named secret that is stored in the vault.

I thought I'd be able pull it out something like this:

```
builder.getSecret('DevDbPassword');
```

So that I can use to update the password using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder.

Can somebody help with figuring out how to get the secret?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you want to get the secret in Configuration Builder? You can get secret this way:

```
     AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
     KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
     var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://<YourKeyVaultName>.vault.azure.net/secrets/AppSecret")
             .ConfigureAwait(false);
     Message = secret.Value;
```

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app) for more details.

If you still want to get the secret in Configuration Builder, you can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-dotnet-core-quickstart).

```
public string Message { get; set; }

public AboutModel(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

private readonly IConfiguration _configuration = null;

public void OnGet()
{
    Message = "My key val = " + _configuration["AppSecret"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/manage-secrets-with-azure-key-vault/5-access-secrets-from-web-app?pivots=csharp) walks through it start to finish (make sure you're looking at the C# version).

Once you have things set up like you have them, your vault's secrets become part of the app's configuration. You need to inject an `IConfiguration` wherever you need a secret and get its value from that.